# Is it possible to pass template context variable as a parameter in a redirect() call

Tags: django, django-views

I am building a job board. This project has a `post_job` view. After successfully posting a job, the user is redirected to the `dashboard` view (a page that shows a list of all their posts).

```
def post_job(request):
   # ... 
   return redirect('dashboard')
```

Is there a way to pass an additional context variable to the dashboard.html template. I.e:

```
return redirect('dashboard', {'success': True})
```

so that I can then say in the dashboard.html file:

```
{% if success %}
  Your job has been posted successfully.
{% endif %}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect cannot take context variables - the 'normal' thing to do would be to tag the jon as 'new' when posted. In 'dashboard' view deal with new jobs differently - for instance if there are any new jobs you can arrange to show the success message - and also update the job from 'new' to 'open'.

Well that is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect returns an [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response, which just tell the browser where to go next. What you could do is store the data you need in your session and access it on your Dashboard view, for example:

```py
def post_job(request):
    ...
    request.session['success'] = True
    return redirect('dashboard')

def dashboard(request):
    success = request.session.pop('success', False)
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context={'success': success})
```